# Passar dados Via Ajax para o Controller MVC ASP.NET CORE C#

Tags: jquery, ajax, controller

Olá, sou iniciante em programação, e estou tentando passar dados via Ajax para o meu Controller, para ser sincero estou apenas estudando então não sei nem ao certo entender as vantagens de Jquery para isso...

Seguindo alguns exemplos, fiz da seguinte forma:

```
var nome = document.getElementById("Nome").value;
var sobrenome = document.getElementById("Sobrenome").value;
var email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
var senha = document.getElementById("Senha").value;

    if (nome == null || nome == "") {
        return alert("FALTA INFORMAÇÃO");
    }
    if (sobrenome == null || sobrenome == "") {
        return alert("FALTA INFORMAÇÃO");
    }
    if (email == null || email == "") {
        return alert("FALTA INFORMAÇÃO");
    }
    if (senha == null || senha == "") {
        return alert("FALTA INFORMAÇÃO");
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../VerificaDuplicidadeCadastro/Home=email?' + email,            
        //data: email,
```

Bom, deixei comentado o 'data' pois nos exemplos todo mundo utiliza isso, mas eu sinceramente não entendo como funciona, por isso tentei passar o email pela URL mesmo, mas no meu controller estou recebendo o valor nulo.

Segue o controller:

```
public IActionResult VerificaDuplicidadeCadastro(string email)
    {

        var con = new Conexao();

        con.OpenConnection();

        con.CloseConnection();

        return Json(true);

    }
```

Como posso fazer isso adequadamente?

Obrigado.

Comment: O `data` vc pode enviar de duas formas: `data: "email="+email` ou `data: {email: email}`.

Comment: @Sam, obrigado pela resposta, mas das duas formas o valor recebido no Controller continua sendo recebido como null.

Answer (score -1):

Olá, bom dia.

Você pode encontrar algumas informações sobre as vantagens e desvantagens de utilizar Ajax [nesta publicação](https://dzone.com/articles/pros-and-cons-of-ajax).

Quando você passa uma informação *"pela URL mesmo"*, o termo que utilizamos é passagem de parâmetros via Query String.

Para realizar a passagem de parâmetros via Query String, precisamos obedecer a seguinte sintaxe:

> URLBase?chave1=valor1&chave2=valor2

Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre a sintaxe da Query String através do seguinte link: [What is the correct syntax for query strings?](https://help.marketruler.com/wiki/What_is_the_correct_syntax_for_query_strings%3F)

Ou seja,  na sua chamada Ajax, você está informando a url desta forma:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "../VerificaDuplicidadeCadastro/Home=email?" + email,            
   //data: email,
```

Perceba que você está invertendo os sinais na sintaxe, onde o corret

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "../VerificaDuplicidadeCadastro/Home?email=" + email,            
   //data: email,
```

Faça um teste e veja se resolve o problema. E se não resolver, avise que a gente continua a análise.

--

E sobre a utilização do **data** na chamada Ajax, você consegue encontrar mais informações na própria [API do Jquery.AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Você vai descobrir que pode passar os valores utilizando o formato JSON:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "../VerificaDuplicidadeCadastro/Home",            
   data: { "email": email },
```

Comment: Eduardo, muito obrigado pela resposta...bom, eu tentei passar os dados das duas formas, em ambas o controller nem mesmo foi acessado, e nenhum erro apareceu através do inspecionar do Google Chrome...isto é, a depuração passou direto pelo código Ajax sem entrar no Controller.

Answer (score -1):

No exemplo abaixo tenho um seletor que ao mudar o item selecionado ativa o ajax.

**No .cshtml**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="idSelecao" class="form-control">
        <option>--- Selecione um item---</option>
        <option value="exemplo">exemplo</option>
    </select>
    
    
            <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#idSelecao").on("change", function () {
                var val = $('#idSelecao').val();
                var url = "/SeuController/NoController";
                alert(val);
                $.post(url, { parametro: val }, function (data) {
                   //--
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**No controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void NoController(string parametro)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parametro))
        {
            TempData["parametro"] = parametro;
        }
    }
```